# What is a practical application of using an immutable type in a thread-safe way that differs from using a mutable type in the same way?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the following code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static object locker = new object();
        static string data;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000);

                    string localCopy;
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        localCopy = data;
                    }

                    // do some read operation with localCopy; 
                    // write to log file, call a web API, etc
                    Log(localCopy);
                }
            });

            while(true)
            {
                // data is written to from time to time on the main thread;
                // can be user input, etc.
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                lock(locker)
                {
                    data = input;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Since .NET, strings are immutable, and one of the benefits of immutability is thread safety, are the `lock` statements necessary?

**EDIT**: I chose an immutable type, `string` in the above example, just for context; I am generally trying to understand the "thread-safe" property of immutable types, if, based on comments (and my own understanding of things), some sort of `lock` semantics is still necessary in multi-threaded code when using such types cross-thread.

Comment: The `String` *object* is thread-safe. The *variable* naming the stream is what is guarded with the `lock`.

Comment: @user2864740 can you please elaborate on that? Are you saying `string data` names a ... stream? Is `data` not a `string` object?

Comment: I don't think your code provides the safety you desire, either. It seems entirely possible that you could reassign `data` multiple times before your consumer is able to read and process it. I think you want something more like a semaphore (e.g. `SemaphoreSlim`) so that you don't miss any items.

Comment: user2864740 means that fields and variables are references to memory. They are not immutable. The memory objects that they reference can be immutable. `data = a; data = b;` changes which memory `data` is pointing at.

Comment: @John I agree, I was trying to make a simple example, so for purpose of this question let's presume that `data` is not re-assigned before logged. The question is specifically about needing to lock an immutable type, such as string.

Comment: @user2864740 I agree with that statement; where does the stream you mentioned come in? Are you calling the memory a string object is pointing to a stream?

Comment: Without `lock` here, you have a scenario where `if (data == "test" && data == "test")` could return false, but `if (data == "test" || data == "test")` in its place would return true.

Comment: @John you're referring to `data` changing between the two evaluations, sure. Would that not be the case for any type?  I am trying to understand the "immutable types are thread-safe" idea - it appears we still need locks, regardless of whether or not the type is immutable.

Comment: @CoolBots I am, and it is indeed the case for any type. `lock` would prevent this problem from occurring. I was merely emphasising that even with an immutable type this problem exists because you're changing the memory that `data` references.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what part is strange/seems wrong to you?

Comment: @CoolBots - The thread-safety of immutable types is basically "so long as you don't re-assign the variable holding your immutable data then multiple threads can access your immutable data simultaneously". You are re-assigning `data` so your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Enigmativity is that statement not true of mutable types as well? Basically, you're saying "as long as you're just reading the data"... What is the practical application of using an immutable type in a thread-safe way that differs from using a mutable type in the same way?

Comment: @CoolBots Oops! That was a typo / phone auto 'correction' - should have been "string" there as well D:

Comment: @user2864740 lol, thank you for clarifying that! Given your rep, I figured I am missing some key knowledge about strings, so I had it on my list of things to look up and figure out; you saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: As I guess you've already figured out: mutating an object is different to replacing the object. You are not mutating the string, you are replacing it. That's the difference.

Comment: @CoolBots - By virtual of an immutable type being unchangable you can be certain that a rogue thread can not cause any mutations. That's what makes immutable objects thread-safe. What you can't control, necessarily, is the original variable declaration when the immutable object was created. If multiple threads have access to overwrite the variable then you lose the thread-safety. With mutable objects then rogue threads can go to town and do nasty things to your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a practical application of using an immutable type in a thread-safe way that differs from using a mutable type in the same way?

As noted in the comments, it's all about the variables.

If you have multiple threads accessing the same variable, then yes, you have to protect the variable in some way (`lock`, `Interlocked`, etc).

The benefit of immutable types comes in when you pass that data to another thread - creating another variable. All you need to do is copy the reference from one variable to another, and now the first variable can change however much it wants; the second variable remains immutable.

I think it's a bit easier to understand with an example like `ImmutableStack<string>`. Let's say there's a "main" thread that pushes and pops that `ImmutableStack<string>`; since this is immutable, each push/pop updates its own variable. If our "main" thread wants to give another thread a *snapshot*, it just copies its current variable to another variable for that thread. Then the "main" thread can continue pushing/popping/updating its own variable with impunity. The "secondary" thread has its own immutable snapshot.

In a more general situation, this can be useful with one or more readers/responders, where each "read" loop starts with capturing the current state of the shared variable and using that local copy for the duration of the loop.

If you wanted to snapshot a mutable value, that would require doing a deep clone. Imagine if `string` was mutable, like it is in other languages. In that case, copying the value (reference) of the string would be insufficient; one thread could change a single character while another thread was trying to do something else with the value. In order to capture a true snapshot of a mutable string value, you'd have to copy the entire string to a new string.

There are other benefits to immutable types in general (design, etc), but this "reference snapshot" benefit is one that specifically benefits multithreading.